# How to use only if-else in constructor of class when the class only got final fields?

Tags: java, class, constructor

I have written the following constructor for a given class

```
public Gerade(Punkt punkt1, Punkt punkt2) {

        if (!punkt1.equals(punkt2)) {
            if (punkt1.getX().equals(punkt1.getX().min(punkt2.getX()))) {
                this.p1 = punkt1;
                this.p2 = punkt2;
            } else if (punkt2.getX().equals(punkt1.getX().min(punkt2.getX()))) {
                this.p1 = punkt2;
                this.p2 = punkt1;
            } else if (punkt1.getX().equals(punkt2.getX())) {
                if (punkt1.getY().equals(punkt1.getY().min(punkt2.getY()))) {
                    this.p1 = punkt1;
                    this.p2 = punkt2;
                } else if (punkt2.getY().equals(punkt1.getY().min(punkt2.getY()))) {
                    this.p1 = punkt2;
                    this.p2 = punkt1;
                }
            }
            } else {
            System.out.println("Punkte are identical!");
            this.p1 = null;
            this.p2 = null;
        }

}
```

as well as the following two final fields:

```
private final Punkt p1;
private final Punkt p2;
```

irregardless of what the code is actually doing: The issue is, I get a compile error, because if, for any reason, the two passed variables punkt1 and punkt2 happen not to be compatible with the if-else cases in the constructor, the final fields might not become initialized. (which I find quite strange, because the else case should account for literally anything else that could be coming around, shouldn't it?)

Problem is, since they have to be final, I also cannot write a "standard case" into the constructor outside and before or after the if-else construct, because then the fields can either not be set again by the if-else construct (if standard case before), or they might have already gotten set by the if-else construct and thus cannot be initialized again afterwards (if standard case after).

I can also not use any setters, since the fields are final. Last but not least, I am not supposed to implement any other constructor.

Is there any way to get around this, possibly? Any help would be super appreciated!

Comment: The reason is quite simple: not all branches initialize both `p1` and `p2`, and the compiler does not allow this. All `if` statements need and `else` block, so the compiler knows that you have covered all cases.

Comment: Your outermost `if` doesn't implement the `else` case. So not all paths are covered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to not initialise your field. You have to handle all cases:

```
public Gerade(Punkt punkt1, Punkt punkt2) {

    if (!punkt1.equals(punkt2)) {
      if (punkt1.getX().equals(punkt1.getX().min(punkt2.getX()))) {
        this.p1 = punkt1;
        this.p2 = punkt2;
      } else if (punkt2.getX().equals(punkt1.getX().min(punkt2.getX()))) {
        this.p1 = punkt2;
        this.p2 = punkt1;
      } else if (punkt1.getX().equals(punkt2.getX())) {
        if (punkt1.getY().equals(punkt1.getY().min(punkt2.getY()))) {
          this.p1 = punkt1;
          this.p2 = punkt2;
        } else if (punkt2.getY().equals(punkt1.getY().min(punkt2.getY()))) {
          this.p1 = punkt2;
          this.p2 = punkt1;
        } else {
          //here
          p1 = null;
          p2 = null;
        }
      } else {
        //here
        p1 = null;
        p2 = null;
      }
    } else {
      System.out.println("Punkte are identical!");
      this.p1 = null;
      this.p2 = null;
    }
  }
```

But so many if statements is not a good idea.